# Center two buttons inside a card horizontally

Tags: html, css, materialize

I tried center-align class. The buttons are centered vertically but not horizontally.

[image]

My code:- (I am using react so I have everything in JSX)

```
import React from 'react';

const Landing = () => {
    return (
        <div className="row">
            <div className="card small card-landing valign-wrapper hoverable">
                    <div className="center-align">
                        <a className="waves-effect waves-light btn">Login</a><br />
                    </div>
                    <div className="center-align">
                        <a className="waves-effect waves-light btn">Signup</a>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Landing;
```

Comment: I have added a solution below....See if this resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Because your `.card.valign-wrapper` ia a `flex` row, So you have to apply `justify-content: center` to `.card.valign-wrapper`.

Use below css

```
.card.valign-wrapper {
  justify-content: center;
}

.card.valign-wrapper a.btn {
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.card.valign-wrapper {
  justify-content: center;
}

.card.valign-wrapper a.btn {
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="card small card-landing valign-wrapper hoverable">
    <div class="center-align">
      <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Login</a><br />
    </div>
    <div class="center-align">
      <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Signup</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want the buttons center horizontally and vertically, you can change the CSS class to take these parameters:

```
<div className="background-position: center center">
```

Apply these on both divs.